# Unwrapping issue in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, mutable

I am new to swift, so apologies for funny question, but I am quite tanged in this optional type and the unwrapping thing.

So, I am trying to create a calculator for which I have a UITextField to display the digits while pressed or result after calculation and off course some buttons representing digits.

[image]

Now I have action methods attached which my digit buttons and return button properly.

I have my UITextField declared like following which is implicitly unwrapped and a mutable string array which is also unwrapped-

```
@IBOutlet weak var displayTextField: UITextField!
var digitArray : [String]!
```

The append digit method works fine which just take the digit from the button and displays it in the textfield by appending. But I am getting a Bad Access error in the enter method. I guess, I am trying to add the item in the array improperly. Can anyone please help.

```
@IBAction func appendDigit(sender: UIButton) {
        let digit = sender.currentTitle!
        displayTextField.text = digit + displayTextField.text      
}
@IBAction func enter(sender: UIButton) {
        digitArray.append(displayTextField.text)
}
```

Comment: You just have to initialize your array. Either directly on declaration (`var digitArray: [String] = []`) or at any other point prior using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`digitArray` is declared but not initialized.

```
var digitArray = [String]()
```

The initializer syntax is either a pair of parentheses after the type `let x = Type()` or in case of an array with the type annotation and a pair of square brackets `let x : [Type] = []`.

As the compiler infers the type, the declaration `[String]` is not needed.

Declare variables non optional whenever possible, you will get more and better help by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Convert initializer to

```
var digitArray = [String]()
```